# SSRS split multivariable param and EXEC sql string with LIKEs BY REPLACE function

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, replace, exec, quotes

Need your help. I am trying to split string with multiple variables that will come from SSRS user report to make LIKE conditions:

```
 WHERE ppc.prime_name LIKE '501%'
    OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '502%'
    OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '503%'
    OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '504%'
    OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '505%'
```

It give more performance than next solution:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(ppc.prime_name,1,6) IN (@BINS)
```

So I want to execute next sql commands:

```
DECLARE @BINS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

SET @BINS = '501,502,503,504,505' --error in this line
SET @SQL = '
SELECT ppc.prime_coc
FROM [dbo].[tablename] ppc with(nolock)
WHERE ppc.prime_name LIKE ''''' + REPLACE(@BINS,',','%'''' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''''') + '%'''''


--PRINT @SQL    
CREATE TABLE #tmpBIN (prime_coc uniqueidentifier)
INSERT INTO #tmpBIN
EXEC (@SQL)
```

I am getting error: Incorrect syntax near '501'. I don't understand what is a problem. If I execute just print @SQL - I receive well formed sql command to run:

```
SELECT ppc.prime_coc
FROM [dbo].[tablename] ppc with(nolock)
WHERE ppc.prime_name LIKE ''501%'' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''502%'' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''503%'' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''504%'' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''505%''
```

Need your advice. Thank you.

---

NEW DETAILS:
Guys, I got error message in SSRS report: "The replace function requires 3 argument(s)". I have choose int type of multiple variable, it didn't help. Any ideas how to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: If you print your select its pretty clear whats wrong with your SQL - You  have too many ' tokens

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead in your dynamic SQL - As you can see in your print out, you have double tokens, and that is of cause not allowed.

```
SET @BINS = '501,502,503,504,505' --error in this line
SET @SQL = '
SELECT ppc.prime_coc
FROM [dbo].[tablename] ppc with(nolock)
WHERE ppc.prime_name LIKE ''' + REPLACE(@BINS,',','%'' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE ''') + '%'''
```

**Print Statement**

```
SELECT ppc.prime_coc
FROM [dbo].[tablename] ppc with(nolock)
WHERE ppc.prime_name LIKE '501%' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '502%' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '503%' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '504%' OR ppc.prime_name LIKE '505%'
```

Comment: @user2974764 Glad I could help. Remember to mark the answer as correct so others can find it helpful.

Comment: Thomas, SQL Script is working, but when I place it in SSRS report Dataset, I got error. Updated information higher.